# Ubuntu 18.04.1 + VirtualBox 5.2.22 - VM hangs/freezes when I press printscreen button

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am running Virtualbox 5.2.22 on Windows 10. The VM is a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 with 6 processors, 8GB of RAM, and 128 Video RAM. Guest additions is installed. If I press the printscreen button inside the Ubuntu guest, the VM freezes/hangs and I have to force a shut down. Any ideas on where to start debugging this problem?